Eigenvalues of Laplace operator and Schrödinger operator
When reading the paper Control for Schrödinger operators on tori by N.Burq and M.Zworski (Math. Res. Lett., 19(2):309–324, 2012), an inequality confused me:
Define the flat torus $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{R}^2/A\mathbb{Z}\times B\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $u_0\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$. $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $V\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is a smooth potential.
We define
$$
v_{\varepsilon,0}=\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left(e^{-i\varepsilon(-\Delta+V)}-I \right) u_0.
$$
We can write $u_0$ in terms of orthonormal eigenvectors of Schrödinger operator $-\Delta+V: u_0=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(-\Delta+V)}u_{0,\lambda}e_\lambda$, then we have
$$
\left \| v_{0,\alpha}-v_{0,\beta} \right \| _{H^{-4}}^2 \leq \sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(-\Delta+V)} \left | \frac{e^{-i\alpha \lambda}-1}{\alpha}-\frac{e^{-i\beta \lambda}-1}{\beta} \right | ^2 (1+\lambda)^{-2}\left | u_{0,\lambda} \right |^2. 
$$
What confused me is the term $(1+\lambda)^{-2}$.
I know the definition of the norm $\left \| u_0  \right \| _{H^{-4}}=\left \| (1-\Delta)^{-2}u_0  \right \|_{L^2}$, but what is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $-\Delta$ and $-\Delta+V$?
Why we can "substitute" the eigenvalues of $-\Delta+V$ into the position of $-\Delta$?
Thanks in advance!

I don't think this can be right. If we take $u_0$ as an eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ and $V$ as a large constant and $\alpha,\beta$ such that $e^{i\alpha V}=e^{i\beta V}=1$, then the RHS almost computes the norm exactly. More specifically, we are off by a factor of $(1+\lambda)^2/(1+\lambda+V)^2$, and this we can make small.

I have asked Professor Burq why the inequality holds.
He told me that we can add the potential and have an equivalent norm.
So it should be $\lesssim$ rigorously.

Nice, but could you elaborate a little more? After all the question was upvoted so every nice answer is interesting for at least few other members.

@DanieleTampieri OK. Thanks for the reminder. I'll add some details later.
